# Ubuntu Moving root folder to a new lvm partition

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, init

I began running out of space on my `/` partition<sup>*</sup>. So I decided to create a new lvm partition and move to that one instead. Now, I have created the lvm partition, mounted it, rsync folders from / to that lvm (except dev,sys,proc ofcourse.). Got grub configured to pass the lvm uuid during boot. Now I am getting errors

```
/sbin/init not found.
```

and throws me back to the initramfs prompt. Now part of this lvm partition is in an external harddisk. When i login to the non-lvm system and check the dmesg (within the lvm partition) it gives me this:

```
[   72.040533] sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 sdc4 < sdc5 > 
[   72.111571] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   72.111583] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[   76.218394] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
[   80.090891] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
[  137.010053] Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = -100041832 ns)
[  338.315648] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[  338.812824] udev[2886]: starting version 163
[  348.356446] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, address 5
[  349.220933] udev[2950]: starting version 163
```

Here sdb2 is the non-lvm root partition.  sdc must be the ext. hd. 
Anybody, has any solutions??

<sup>*</sup>-Don't ask, i was stupid during the installation.:(

Answer (score 0):

I may need to update the initram fs.

Boot on a live CD and mount your system and it's subdirectories, then attach system folders like this:

```
mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/myroot/dev
mount -t proc none /mnt/myroot/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/myroot/sys
mount -t devpts none /mnt/myroot/dev/pts
```

Then you have to chroot into it and launch the `update-initramfs` command (with some arguments I don't remember). It will rebuild the initrd file located in /boot

Google about how to update-initramfs from a liveCD.

I have to warn you that you might screw your system even worse than it is right now.

Good luck.

Comment: I finally got it working. it had nothing to do with update-initramfs, but a usb hd partition failing to mount during bootup(udev process)

Comment: Glad you made it working. Sad my answer was useless :P

Comment: well i did learn the system folders that are relevant and what to do when i  move the root folder. so thanks. :)